# Copy object with specified variable

Tags: javascript, object

I want to copy/extend/spread an object that uses any local variable in one file, into another file but with changed variable value.

Example:

Version1.js

```
const values = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
export default {
  key1: values,
  handler1: (param) => {
    if (values.indexOf(param) > -1) {
      console.log('something')
    }
    console.log('anything else')
  }
}
```

Version2.js

```
import Version1 from './Version1'
const values = ['a','b','c','d','e'] // changed values
export default copiedWithVariableChange(Version1, {values}) // IS THIS POSSIBLE ??
```

I CAN make a function that exports the object. And then pass required values in the function. But is there any other way to achieve what I want ?

I am not entirely sure if this is possible, but if it is, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Not possible without something silly like `eval`ing the function's code into a new function that uses your own closure (or just writing out the whole function again). If you need to do this, consider having `Version1` export a function rather than an object - call the function with no parameters to get the default `values`, otherwise pass the `values` you want

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes the function method is always there, I have also mentioned it in the question that I can do it that ways. But I was wondering if there are ways by which I could `bind` the `Version1` file itself ? as we do with functions

Comment: No, you can't alter the closure data seen by a function without entirely re-creating your own function

Comment: @CertainPerformance By function you mean file ? Because we CAN bind the function's `this` and use variables inside `this`. And since it can be done with functions, I was wondering if the same thing can be done with files as well

Comment: No, I mean function - a function's LexicalEnvironment (the scoped variables it sees) cannot be changed unless you can change those scoped variables yourself, which you can't if you're accessing the function from a different file. Though, in this instance you could *mutate* `Version1.key1`, but mutating imported objects is rarely a good idea. `this` isn't being used here, so `bind` won't do anything useful